# Is there any way to find the duplicate items inside of a map matching only selected values?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have declared one ArrayList and another LinkedHashMap, they are globally declared as:-

```
List<ItemTrack> itemTracks = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<ItemTrack>> duplicateFileItems = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

In LinkedHashMap String is used to hold the name of the file.

ItemTrack is a model class and contains:-

```
String mfgPart;
String mfgName;
String partNo;
String rowNo;
```

What I want is duplicate list of ItemTracks along with the file name. mfgPart, mfgName, partNo should be same in order to be considered as duplicate but rowNo can be neglected.  How can i achieve this?

So far I have I have tried this:-

```
Map<String ,List<ItemTrack>> allValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, List<ItemTrack>> duplicateValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<ItemTrack>> itm : duplicateFileItems.entrySet()) {
            for(ItemTrack itms : itm.getValue()){
if(!allValues.){ //I'm stuck here
                    duplicateValues.put(itm.getKey(),itm.getValue());
                }
            }
```

Any suggestions or solutions will be provided by you is always welcome.

Comment: Override hashcode and equals method of ItemTrack to consider for duplicate values.

Comment: @GauravJeswani are there any simpler way to achieve this? Thanks for your comment.